# Define Python function that returns True if the values in the input list alternately go up and down(in a strict manner)

Tags: python-3.x

```
def alternating(l):
  f=0
  if len(l)==0 or len(l)==1:
  f=1
  for i in range(0,len(l)):
    if i==len(l)-3:
      break
    if l[i]<l[i+1]:
      if l[i+1]>l[i+2]:
        f=1

    if l[i]>l[i+1]:
      if l[i+1]<l[i+2]:
        f=1

  if f==1:
    return(True)
  if f==0:
    return(False)
```

I have tried this logic but not working.
i want to solve this problem.
returns True if the values in the input list alternately go up and down.

Comment: Line 4 in your code has wrong indentation

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will do what you're after.

This code works both ways `up -> down -> up` and `down -> up -> down`

```
def is_alternating(lst):
    # check if list is valid
    if len(lst) < 3:
        return False

    # get stating direction
    # first element > second = up -> down
    # up is True, down is False
    direction = lst[0] > lst[1]

    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        if direction:
            if not lst[i] > lst[i + 1]:
                return False
        else:
            if not lst[i] < lst[i + 1]:
                return False

        # invert direction
        direction = not direction
    return True

# Output
>>> is_alternating( [1, 2, 3, 4] )
False
>>> is_alternating( [1, 2, 0, 4] )
True
>>> is_alternating( [5, 2, 8, 4] )
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.cycle` with `operator.lt` and `operator.gt` here to handle which delta you wish to check next and pair up each adjacent elements using `zip`, then use the builtin `all` function to make sure that all comparisons are `True`, eg:

```
from itertools import cycle
from operator import lt, gt

def is_alternating(seq):
    # First element must be less, next must be more, repeat...
    # (can be changed to lt, lt, lt, gt or whatever pattern is required)
    ops = cycle([lt, gt])
    # Zip the ops and the pairs of numbers
    it = zip(ops, zip(seq, seq[1:]))
    # Check that all operations return True - will short circuit on False
    return all(f(a, b) for f, (a, b) in it)

for sequence in [[1, 3, 2], [1], [], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7]]:
    print(sequence, '->', is_alternating(sequence))
```

Gives you:

```
[1, 3, 2] -> True
[1] -> True
[] -> True
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> False
[2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7] -> True
```

Comment: `ops = cycle(...) ;  zip(cycle(ops), ...)` you wrap a cycle inside a cycle?  Also you are using `zip(seq, seq[1:])` when there is a nice iterator friendly [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise#itertools-recipes) recipe in the itertools documentation.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen ahh thanks for the catch of the `cycle` - didn't catch that when I refactored a couple of bits... And true about `pairwise`...

Answer (score 0):

We define alternating as each pair of elements `((s[0],s[1]), (s[1],s[2]) ... )` to have the opposite relation (`a<b`) then the previous/next pairs. Also if any pair are equal to each other then the sequence is not alternating, meaning the exact function would look like this:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def alternating(seq):
    last = None
    for a,b in pairwise(seq):
        if a==b or (a<b) == last:
            return False
        else:
            last = a<b
    return True
```

note that this would return `True` for sequences with 2 or less elements, if that is not the desired behaviour you would need to add a `if len(seq)<3:return False` although then this method would not work with iterators like generators.

Answer (score 0):

Start from index i element and compare with previous and next element with it.
I check if element at index i greater than previous and next element or if it is less than previous and next element.
If one of the condition become False then list does not contain alternating elements.

`def alternating(l):
    if l == [] or len(l) == 1:
        return True 
    for i in range(1,len(l)-1):
        if l[i] > l[i-1]:
            if not l[i] > l[i+1]:

                return False
        elif l[i] < l[i-1]:
            if not l[i] < l[i+1]:
                return False
    return True`

Answer (score 0):

Did the following steps.-
 1. -If the length of list is 0 or 1, return false.
 2. if two adjacent element of the list is same then return false.
 3. checking the consistency of the list, if it is alternating or not.
 4. If not then return false otherwise return true.

```
def alternating(l): # l is a list !
if len(l) == 0 or len(l) == 1:
    return True
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i]==l[i+1]:
        return False
for i in range(2,len(l)):
    if l[i-2]>l[i-1] :
        if  (l[i]<l[i-1]):
            return False
    elif l[i-2]<l[i-1]:
        if  (l[i] > l[i - 1]):
            return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def alternating(l):  
    a=b=c=d=0  
    if len(l)==0 or len(l)==1 or (len(l)==2 and l[0]!=l[1]):  
        return ("True") 

    for i in range(0,len(l)-1,2):  
        if(l[i]<l[i+1]):  
            a+=1  
        if(l[i]>l[i+1]):  
            b+=1  

    if a!=len(l)//2 and b!= len(l)//2:  
            return("False")  

    for i in range(1,len(l)-1,2):  
        if(l[i]<l[i+1]):  
            c+=1  
        if(l[i]>l[i+1]):  
            d+=1  

    if c!=(len(l)-1)//2 and d!= (len(l)-1)//2:  
        return("False")  

    if a==d or b==c:  
        return("True")  
    return("False")
```

Comment: Please explain the changes you made, don't just post a correction without explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = list()
n = int(input("How many numbers you want to enter in list:"))
for i in range(n):
    ele = int(input())
    list1.append(ele)
print(list1)

if(list1[0]==9 or list1[1]== 9 or list1[2]==9 or list1[3]==9):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26243372)

Comment: I’d add to @double-beep’s point: This is especially important with old questions that have a lot of existing answers. Why should someone prefer your approach over the top voted answer? Is there something that your answer improves upon compared to the current solutions?

Answer (score -1):

```
def alternating(x):
    if len(x)==0:
        return(True)
    for i in range(0,len(x)-2):
        if x[i]==x[i+2]:
            return(True)
    else:
        return(False)
```

Comment: Shame this wont work .... what if the sequence is 0, 1, -15, 12 - it follows the rules - it goes alternating up and down ... but your code will return False :-(

Comment: for 0,1,-15,12 it should be false only

Comment: you don't have any alternating numbers in your sequence so it should be FALSE ONLY.  if you will elaborate i will be glad to learn- @Tony Suffolk 66

Comment: The question isn't about alternating numbers it is about a sequence which 'goes up and down in a strict manner'. I understood this to mean that the 2nd number should be larger than the first, the 3rd number should be smaller than the 2nd, the 4th should be larger than the 3rd etc. The main problem is that the requirement is horribly written and is clearly ambiguous - When I read it I cannot get where you read 'alternating' which proves the ambiguity.